# Load .py file in Jupyter fails - Windows

Tags: python, windows, file, jupyter-notebook

I am working in Windows 10 and when trying to load a .py file into Jupyter Lab, I am facing the following error:

```
%run -i 'C:\\Users\\MGMZ\\Desktop\\Analysis\\file_v2.py'

Exception: File `"'C:\\\\Users\\\\MGMZ\\\\Desktop\\\\Analysis\\\\file_v2.py'.py"` not found.
```

The file is obviously sitting in that exact location. I have tried to use `\`, `/` and other combinations but withoyt success.

Any clue what can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without quotes:

```
%run -i C:\\Users\\MGMZ\\Desktop\\Analysis\\file_v2.py
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. That is just how I have it in the first place, with '\\'

Comment: How about without no quotes at all?

Comment: indeed that solve the issue!! Can you please modify your answer to approve it?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you should remove the quotes in 'C:\Users\MGMZ\Desktop\Analysis\file_v2.py'.

Put this bite of code C:\Users\MGMZ\Desktop\Analysis\file_v2.py and then it will work.

In Jupyter we don't use quotes to go to any location.